# onFocusChange do something then set focus back to same view

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to make an activity which will work with a bluetooth barcode reader.

I want to be able to either check the checkbox or not and then on pressing Next on softkeyboard move the focus to etReturnsUniqueNo.  I will then scan the barcode which will enter the number and move the focus onto the next input.  I want the details of the inputs to then be displayed in etReturnsLast and the focus set back to etReturnsUniqueNo.

The problem is I have a double cursor thing going on, both etReturnsUniqueNo and etReturnsLast have cursors showing, with etReturnsLast being the one where the next text is entered, not sure why?  Can anyone explain whats happening and maybe show me how it should be??

MainActivity.Java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private CheckBox chkReturnsInstore;
    private EditText etReturnsUniqueNo;
    private EditText etReturnsLast;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initViews();
        initListeners();
        initObjects();

        Returns();
    }

    private void initViews() {

        chkReturnsInstore = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkReturnsInstore);
        etReturnsUniqueNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etReturnsUniqueNo);
        etReturnsLast = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etReturnsLast);

    }

    /**
     * This method is to initialize listeners
     */
    private void initListeners() {    }

    private void initObjects(){    }

    public void Returns() {

        //OnUniqueNumber Lost focus
        etReturnsUniqueNo.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (!hasFocus){
                    String[] data = new String[2];

                    data[0] = etReturnsUniqueNo.getText().toString().trim();
                    if (chkReturnsInstore.isChecked()){
                        data[1] = "Y";
                    }else {
                        data[1] = "N";
                    }

                    //Show details in etNewLast
                    String line = "";
                    String newline = "";
                    line = etReturnsLast.getText().toString();
                    for (int i=0; i<2;i++) {
                        if(i<1) {
                            newline = newline + data[i] + ",";
                        }else{
                            newline = newline + data[i] + "\n";
                        }
                    }
                    newline = newline + line;
                    etReturnsLast.setText(newline);
                    etReturnsUniqueNo.setText("");
                    etReturnsUniqueNo.requestFocus();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/clStorageMenu"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/clStorageReturns"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="462dp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/clStorageMenu"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/clStorageMenu"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chkReturnsInstore"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etReturnsUniqueNo"
        android:layout_width="198dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/chkReturnsInstore" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etReturnsLast"
        android:layout_width="396dp"
        android:layout_height="284dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:verticalScrollbarPosition="defaultPosition"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etReturnsUniqueNo"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvReturnsInstore"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="Instore?"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/chkReturnsInstore"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.772"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvReturnsUniqueNo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Unique Number"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/etReturnsLast"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/etReturnsUniqueNo"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.636"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvReturnsInstore"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.109" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code sends the cursor back to etReturnsUniqueNo.  Place below the other listener.

```
    etReturnsLast.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus){
                etReturnsUniqueNo.requestFocus();
            }
        }
    });
```